# Auto create KafkaListeners

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-webflux, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I work with apache-kafka and web flux (spring boot) and I want to know if there is a method to auto create a `KafkaListener` for each topic I add in application.yml(or properties)

Comment: I want to say its not possible. The consumers actually need to **_do something_**, even if they were created automatically. In other words, what would processing those records actually look like?

Comment: KafkaListener is a compiled code with method and annotation on it. How would you create such a code at runtime? And why you cannot feed all your topics to a single predefined KafkaListener?

Comment: please how can I Create get method(localhost:8080/topic/{name}) and read from a specific topic with one listener ??

Answer (score 0):

This is not what consumer is for. The Kafka topic is a stream of data constantly changing . What is business purpose of that http request? Maybe you want to stream such a topic request to the `Flux`? Then consider to use Spring Integration dynamic flows and its `toReactivePublisher()` feature:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-runtime-flows

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/reactive-streams.html#java-dsl

This sample shows something about Kafka and dynamic flows: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/main/dsl/kafka-dsl.

Also this one demonstrates some “to WebFlux” technique : https://github.com/artembilan/sandbox/tree/master/amqp-to-webflux.

Or you can look into Reactor Kafka: https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/reference/.